# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I'm working with PHP, JSON, and Android to create mobile app that can retrieve data from MySQL database. I'm able to get all data from database but, when I try to get a specific data based on the user input I'm unable to get the data. I've try to discovered the solution through the google but I can't solve it. I got the following error from the logcat :

```
05-20 08:44:28.152: E/JSON Parser(313): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject<br />
05-20 08:44:28.152: E/JSON Parser(313): <b>Warning</b>:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\android\getSpesificName.php</b> on line <b>31</b><br />
05-20 08:44:28.152: E/JSON Parser(313): {"success":1,"mahasiswa":null}
05-20 08:44:28.152: D/Specific name(313): {"mahasiswa":[{"nama_mhs":"kurnianto"},{"nama_mhs":"amjad"},{"nama_mhs":"oki"},{"nama_mhs":"tes"},{"nama_mhs":"coba"},{"nama_mhs":"raditya"},{"nama_mhs":"edwin"}],"success":1}
```

This is my 
PHP code  http://pastebin.com/dbUr5DZj
JSONParser class  http://pastebin.com/FYXsWyr4
Specific class  http://pastebin.com/UkSdh3BN

Any help will be appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: Load your webservice in browser and check the response. Are you really getting JSON formatted response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error on line 29 of your PHP file. The line:

```
$respone["mahasiswa"] = array();
```

Should be:

```
$response["mahasiswa"] = array();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I did not pay attention to the little thing like that.